# reduce into object orientated javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have writen a little javascript. It is one of my first and I am still learning.  I would like to reduce the line count and make it more efficient.  I believe that Object Orientated Programming will be my best choice.

The script assigns a class to a button on hover. 
gets elements with that class and performs various if functions to determine if the src attribute of the image button should be changed.  The script also changes another image src attribute at the same time.

I am wondering if I can somehow condense the logic of the if statements into just one or two, then using variables perform the src attribute changes.  But I dont know how to go about this...?

```
    //assign navButtons to var buttons (creates array)
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");

//set buttonHover function
function buttonOn(){
    if ( arrow == topArrow.mouseout ) {
        newArrow = document.getElementById("topArrow");
        newArrow.setAttribute("src", topArrow.mouseover);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", topArrow.text);
    }
    if ( arrow == rightArrow.mouseout ) {
        newArrow = document.getElementById("rightArrow");
        newArrow.setAttribute("src", rightArrow.mouseover);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", rightArrow.text);
    }
    if ( arrow == bottomArrow.mouseout ) {
        newArrow = document.getElementById("bottomArrow");
        newArrow.setAttribute("src", bottomArrow.mouseover);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", bottomArrow.text);
    }
    if ( arrow == leftArrow.mouseout ) {
        newArrow = document.getElementById("leftArrow");
        newArrow.setAttribute("src", leftArrow.mouseover);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", leftArrow.text);
    } 
}

//set buttonHover function
function buttonOff(){
    if ( arrow != topArrow.mouseout ) {
        resetArrow = document.getElementById("topArrow");
        resetArrow.setAttribute("src", topArrow.mouseout);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", start.text);
    }
    if ( arrow != rightArrow.mouseout ) {
        resetArrow = document.getElementById("rightArrow");
        resetArrow.setAttribute("src", rightArrow.mouseout);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", start.text);
    }
    if ( arrow != bottomArrow.mouseout ) {
        resetArrow = document.getElementById("bottomArrow");
        resetArrow.setAttribute("src", bottomArrow.mouseout);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", start.text);
    }
    if ( arrow != leftArrow.mouseout ) {
        resetArrow = document.getElementById("leftArrow");
        resetArrow.setAttribute("src", leftArrow.mouseout);
        menuText.setAttribute("src", start.text);
    }
}

//for each instance of buttons, assign class "active" onmouseover
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    buttons[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "active";
        arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        //get attribute
        arrow = arrow[0].getAttribute("src");
        console.log(arrow);
        buttonOn();
    };
}

//for each instance of buttons, remove class "active" onmouseout
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    buttons[i].onmouseout = function () {
        arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        //get attribute
        arrow = arrow[0].getAttribute("src");
        buttonOff();
        this.className = "";
    };
}
```

Any help would be ace!

## [The JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentieo/9gvEU/)

Comment: Looks like you should start using jQuery, the sooner the better.

Comment: Hi, only really just getting my head around javascript vanilla.  I have heard that it is better to get a good grasp before learning a library?

Comment: Well, you certainly should learn the syntax and what is "document", "window", "console" etc, but things to manipulate DOM are pretty much useless once you move to jQuery. It makes everything a million times easier.

Comment: Why don't you pass `arrow` as a function argument rather than having it global? Same could be said for the other variables you're using.

Comment: I like the sound of that...not quite sure about how to evaluate it though.  Wouldn't I still need to check against 4 static variables leading to four statements of which to change?

Answer (score 2):

Don't handle everything in JS, you can simply set a background image on the available anchor tags without using an img tag and then change the background image on :hover (best would be to use sprites). The only part where JS should kick in would be to change the text image, but there also not by changing an img tag src attribute.
You should preload all the text images as content (with a sensible alt text), position them over one another and then show/hide them according to what button was hovered.

Maybe I'll adjust your fiddle if I get to it but you could probably already optimize it with these information yourself.

Comment: Nice... I had originally tried to achieve this with just css and found it impossible.  Now returning to css I see it would be possible to do everything without js (although your suggestion using js does seem very elegant)  Thanks for the input.. I will have a tinker and see what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve the `buttonOn` function a bit, by removing the `if` statements and replacing them with a call to a factory class of some kind. For example:

```
function ArrowHandlerFactory(){    
    var self = this;

    self.Create = function(arrow) {        
        alert(arrow);
        if ( arrow == topArrow.mouseout ) {

            return new topArrowHandler();
        }
    }

    return {
        Create: self.Create
    }
}

var topArrowHandler = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.ArrowPressed = function() {
        newArrow = document.getElementById("topArrow");
    newArrow.setAttribute("src", topArrow.mouseover);
    menuText.setAttribute("src", topArrow.text);
    }    

    return {
        ArrowPressed: self.ArrowPressed
    }
}

var factory = new ArrowHandlerFactory();

//set buttonHover function
function buttonOn(){
    var handler = factory.Create(arrow);

    handler.arrowPressed();
}
```

The above isn't the complete code, but it gives you the basics to get started.

I'm not stating that the above is the best JavaScript ever, but the core idea of using a factory class, and then a specific class for each arrow direction, is still sound.

Comment: Thanks, that is an approach I did not think of.  I will have to spend some time to really grasp the logic of what you are doing but I get the general idea.